# How to Show Serializer Error in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**I created a register page using the Django rest framework, now I write all validation code in `serializers.py`
and `serializers.py` in writing some errors but I can't see those errors in templates.**

*in serializers.py write some validation like phone number, and password and confirm password is a match or not.*

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        GENDER_CHOICES = [
            ("male", "Male"),
            ("female", "Female"),
            ("other", "Other"),
        ]
    
        gender = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
        class Meta:
            model = Person
            fields = "__all__"
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            gender = validated_data.pop("gender")
            validated_data["gender"] = gender.lower()
            return Person.objects.create(**validated_data)
        
        def validate(self, data: Union[str,int]) -> Union[str,int,None]:
            username = data.get("username")
            password = data.get("password")
            confirmpassword=data.get("confirmpassword")
            phone = data.get("phone")
    
            if Person.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Username is allready exists')
            if len(phone) != 10:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("phone number is not valid")
            if password != confirmpassword:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('password not match')
            return data
```

**views.py**
in `views.py` I also check serializer is valid or not. after then not understand how to write code to show errors in templates.

```
class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = PersonSerializer
        renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
        template_name = "register.html"
    
        def get(self, request: Union[Request, HttpRequest]) -> Union[render, redirect]:
            if "username" in request.session:
                return redirect("home")
            serializer = PersonSerializer()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {"serializer": serializer})
    
        def post(self, request: Union[Request, HttpRequest]) -> Union[redirect, render]:
            serializer = PersonSerializer(data=request.data)
            if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                redirect("register")
            return redirect("login")
```

I expect to show an error in the Templates and that error show with add CSS on that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
except ValidationError as e:
    error_message = str(e.detail['non_field_errors'][0])
    return Response({'error': error_message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Hello, to get error messages from the serializer, you can put "except ValidationError as e" in your view, then you can specifically get just the message and return it as a response, so you can display these messages in the template